# Bridge between two mosquitto brokers

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto

I want to create a bridge between my mosquitto broker which runs on my Raspberry Pi and the mosquitto broker from my PC.

In the mosquitto.conf file (on Raspberry Pi) I set the bridge setting as:

```
connection raspi-PC
address 192.168.0.104:1883 -> Pc address
topic # both 0 local/sensor remote/sensor
```

The connection seems to be fine but when I try to publish on the local topic I cannot see the message in the subscribed client to the remote/topic.

Example:

```
client1 : mosquitto_pub -t local/sensor/room -m "23C"
client2 : mosquitto_sub -h 192.168.0.104 -t remote/sensor/# ->> here is not published msg
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a final `/` on the topic remapping strings, as described in the [mosquitto.conf](http://mosquitto.org/man/mosquitto-conf-5.html) man page. You should use:

```
topic # both 0 local/sensor/ remote/sensor/
```

Comment: It looks as though you publish then subscribe - is that the case? if so, try it the other way around.

Comment: Have you enabled log in mosquitto.conf log_dest destinations